# Can not switch to another page

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is two classes, that I use, and I want to go from home.dart to map.dart

I need to be working that FlatButton, where onPressed is MapPage();

I also tried to add MaterialApp, because anything I have seen is done with that, but I didn't understood how and what is wrong with all of that. StreaProvider I need for the Firebase, so I can't remove this.

Please, help, if you know how. I really need just to switch to a new page

home.dart

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:notifier_app/models/locationCoordinates.dart';
import 'package:notifier_app/screens/map_page/map.dart';
import 'package:notifier_app/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:notifier_app/services/database.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:notifier_app/screens/home/coordinates_list.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  /*final MapPage _mapPage = MapPage();*/

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset(
          "assets/homeBackGround.jpg",
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
          StreamProvider<List<LocationCoordinates>>.value(
            value: DatabaseService().coordinatesOfGPS,
            child: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('Notifier'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                elevation: 0.0,
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton.icon(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.map),
                    label: Text('Map'),
                    textColor: Colors.black54,
                    onPressed: () {
                      MapPage();
                      },
                  ),
                  FlatButton.icon(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                    label: Text('Logout'),
                    textColor: Colors.black54,
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await _auth.signOut();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              body: CoordinatesList(),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

map.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapPageState createState() => _MapPageState();
}

class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {

  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  static const LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.5231563, -122.677433);
  final Set<Marker> _markers = {};
  LatLng _lastMapPosition = _center;
  MapType _currentMapType = MapType.normal;

  static final CameraPosition _position1 = CameraPosition(
    bearing: 192.833,
    target: LatLng(45.531563, -122.677433),
    tilt: 59.440,
    zoom: 11.0,
  );

  Future<void> _goToPosition1() async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_position1));
  }

  _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller){
    _controller.complete(controller);
  }

  _onCameraMove(CameraPosition position){
    _lastMapPosition = position.target;
  }

  _onMapTypeButtonPressed() {
    _currentMapType =
        _currentMapType == MapType.normal ? MapType.satellite : MapType.normal;
  }

  _onAddMarkerButtonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _markers.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(_lastMapPosition.toString()),
        position: _lastMapPosition,
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: 'This is a Title',
          snippet: 'This is a snippet',
        ),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      ));
    });
  }

  Widget button(Function function, IconData icon){
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: function,
      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      child: Icon(
        icon,
        size: 36.0,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Google Map'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: _center,
                zoom:11.0,
              ),
              mapType: _currentMapType,
              markers: _markers,
              onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    button(_onMapTypeButtonPressed, Icons.map),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 16.0,
                    ),
                    button(_onAddMarkerButtonPressed, Icons.add_location),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 16.0,
                    ),
                    button(_goToPosition1, Icons.location_searching),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Navigator` class to go to the new page. You cannot use `Map()`.

Try calling this:

**To Go To New Page**

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>Map());
```

**To Remove this page and return to Previous**

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```